# Assign a function to another

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement a RedBlack Tree, this tree contains some 2D Points. I want to have 2 RedBlack trees, the first one sorts the Points based on their first elements(say x), and the second one sorts them based on the second element(say y). I don't want to have 2 separate trees for this task. so I decided to pass a function to the constructor of a red black tree that compares the points. for example:

```
bool xCompare(Point a, Point b) {return a.x < b.x ;}
bool yCompare(Point a, Point b) {return a.y < b.y ;}
```

So I can Write:

```
RedBlackTree A(xCompare); RedBlackTree B(yCompare);
```

The problem is that I don't know haw can I save this passed function to the constructor so that every time that I call `insert` function, the insertion be based on this passed function. For example if I write:

```
A.insert(make_point(2,3));
A.insert(make_point(7,5));
A.insert(make_point(11,1));
```

The points in `A` should be sorted based on `xCompare`. But I dont know how can I save this `xCompare` function in my class(like a private function) so that `insert` can have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can give your tree a function pointer data member, and set it in the constructor:

```
struct rb_tree
{
  rb_tree(bool(*)(Point a, Point b) cmp) : cmp_(cmp) { .... }
  ....
 private:
  bool (*cmp_)(Point a, Point b);
};
```

Then,

```
rb_tree A(xCompare);
rb_tree(B(yCompare);
```

You can generalize it to any kind of compatible callable object by using a template parameter for the functor, or making the data member an `std::function<bool(Point, Point)>`. For example

```
struct rb_tree
{
  rb_tree(std::function<bool(Point, Point)> cmp) : cmp_(cmp) { .... }
  ....
 private:
  std::function<bool(Point, Point)> cmp_;
};
```

with similar usage to the function pointer example, or

```
template <typename F>
struct rb_tree
{
  rb_tree(F cmp) : cmp_(cmp) { .... }
  ....
 private:
  F cmp_;
};
```

then

```
struct cmpA{ bool operator()(Point a, Point b); };
struct cmpB{ bool operator()(Point a, Point b); };

rb_tree<cmpA> A(cmpA_instance);
rb_tree<cmpB> A(cmpB_instance);
```

Note however that in the last example the types of the trees is different.

Answer (score 1):

First define the comparison function pointer type:

```
typedef bool (*TreeCompare)(Point a, Point b);
```

Then in your class add a member and set it's value in the constructor:

```
class RedBlackTree {
   private:
      TreeCompare m_CompareFunction;
   public:
      RedBlackTree(TreeCompare compareFunction) {
         m_CompareFunction = compareFunction;
      }
      void Insert(Point a, Point b) {
         if(m_CompareFunction(a, b))
             // Do Something
      }
}
```

And finally, create an instance:

```
RedBlackTree myTree(xCompare);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a function pointer approach for this. And also planning to update the answer with a pure object oriented one soon.

```
typedef struct _Point
{
  int x;
  int y;
} Point;

typedef (bool)(*COMPARE)(Point& a, Point& b);

bool xCompare(Point a, Point b) {return a.x < b.x ;}
bool yCompare(Point a, Point b) {return a.y < b.y ;}

Point make_point(int x, int y)
{
  Point pt = {x, y};
  retun pt;
}

class RedBlackTree 
{
  private:
     COMPARE _fnCompare;
  public:
    RedBlackTree(COMPARE compare)
    {
       _fnCompare = compare;
    };

    void Insert(Point ptNew)
    {
       bool bResult = _fnCompare(ptNew);

       if(bResult)
       {
          //Do Something
       }
       else
       {
         //Do something else;
       }
    }
  };

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
    RedBlackTree a(xCompare);

    A.insert(make_point(2,3));
    A.insert(make_point(7,5));
    A.insert(make_point(11,1));

    return 0;
  }
```

Now using a OOPS concept.

```
 typedef struct _Point
 {
   int x;
   int y;
 }

 Point make_point(int x, int y)
 {
   Point pt = {x, y};
   retun pt;
 }

 class IComparer
 {
   public:
       virtual bool Compare(Point& a, Point& b) = 0;
 };

 class AComparer: public IComparer
 {
  public:
    virtual bool Compare(Point& a, Point& b)
    {
      return a.x < b.x ;
    };
 };

 class BComparer: public IComparer
 {
  public:
     virtual bool Compare(Point& a, Point& b)
     {
       return a.y < b.y;
     };
 }

 class RedBlackTree 
 {
   private:
     IComparer * m_pComparer;

   public:

     RedBlackTree(IComparer * comparer)
     {
       m_pComparer = comparer;
     };

     void Insert(Point ptNew)
     {
       bool bResult =  m_pComparer->Compare(ptNew, otherPoint);

       if(bResult)
       {
          //Do Something
       }
       else
       {
           //Do something else;
       }
    }

    ~RedBlackTree()
    {
      delete m_pComparer;
    }
  };

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
    RedBlackTree a(new AComparer());

    A.insert(make_point(2,3));
    A.insert(make_point(7,5));
    A.insert(make_point(11,1));

    return 0;
   }
```